# How to create click events for different text boxes in visual studio 2015

Tags: c#, events, visual-studio-2015, onclick

**What I know:**

In visual Studio 2015 after double-clicking a button, VS will bring the cursor to generated code inside a "button1_click" event.

If a different button is double-clicked, another (completely separate) "button2_click" event is generated.

The same can be said for a **TextBox** being double-clicked; the user is brought to a generated event for "textbox1_textChanged" or a textbox2_textChanged."

**What I want to know:**

When clicking textBox1 in form view, accessing its properties, and clicking "events" and double clicking "Click" at the top, the "textbox1_Click" is generated. (This is good)

However, when clicking a SECOND textbox (textbox2), accessing its properties, Events, and double clicking its "Click" event, it brings the cursor to THE SAME EVENT that was generated for textbox1, aptly named "textbox1_Click." (This is not what I want.)

All I ultimately want is:

```
textbox1_Click {
    textbox1.SelectAll();
}

textbox2_Click {
    textbox2.SelectAll();
}
```

How do I create this SECOND click event for my second textbox (textbox2)?

Is it done with an if statement, possibly using sender or e?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double-clicking the event name (or the object) automatically adds code to the Designer.cs file for your form. That's how the events are linked to their respective controls.

If your two controls are "double-clicking" to the same event handler [and if such behavior is unintentional], fastest fix is to remove the event wire-up from the second control in Designer.cs and double-click the control again.

Look for this line of code:

```
this.textBox2.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.textBox1_Click);
```

Which indicates that your second texbox is wired up to the same event as your first one.

Answer (score 1):

```
void textbox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
         textbox2.SelectAll(); 
    } 
void textbox2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
         textbox2.SelectAll(); 
    }
```

And in designer 
add:

`this.textBox1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.textBox1_Click);`

under textbox1

and 
`this.textBox2.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.textBox2_Click);`
under textbox2
[image]

Alternatively you can add event handlers in your code. It is useful when you create dynamic controls.

Comment: Don't forget to actually bind them to the respective events! `textbox1.Click += textbox1_Click;`